# Route 53 Naked/Root Domain Alias Record

Tags: ssl, heroku, dns, amazon-route53, dnsimple

Route 53 supports Alias records which use Amazon S3 static websites to dynamically resolve naked domains to their www counterparts using a 301 redirect. I am wondering whether the Alias record will support SSL:

http:// example.com -> http:// www.example.com (this will work)
https:// example.com -> https:// www.example.com (will this work?)

I realize that SSL doesn't have anything to do with DNS, but Route 53's implementation of the Alias record (using an S3 static website) concerns me.

It seems like dnsimple's ALIAS record does support SSL:
http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/domain-apex-heroku/

If indeed Route 53 does not support SSL and dnsimple does, how does dnsimple's implementation of the ALIAS record differ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) would be a better place to ask. See [Best StackExchange site for asking about Amazon AWS](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141942/best-stackexchange-site-for-asking-about-amazon-aws).

Answer (score 1):

We bumped into this as well, and it is a "programming" question if you consider the lack of features in current ELB releases.

AWS forums confirm that your scenario is not a supported feature via Route53/ELB (to date): https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=32044

A colleague informed me that if you're subscribed for AWS support, you can contact them for a workaround.